# How to make for loop stop when scanner is at the very end of the input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm currently trying to make a program that will allow the user to enter any amount of integers (I'm only asking them to enter 9 for now as a test) and have the rotateArray function rotate the array of integers. For example:

input: 1 2 3 4 5
output: 5 4 3 2 1

The reason as to why I included the arraylist is because I want to make the program dynamically allocate memory so that the user can enter as many single digit inputs as well. My problem is with a for loop I'm currently using. I"m looking for a way to properly make it so that the for loop stops when it hits the very end of the user's input. I tried using `scan.nextInt().isEmpty()` but that did not work as intended.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program takes two arrays, compares them, and "
        + "determines whether the original array has been rotated and put "
        + "into another array. \nWatch what happens when the original "
        + "array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] is compared to an array  with contents: \n"
        + "[9,7,5,3,1,8,6,4,2,0]");

        int[] original = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[] notRotated = {9,7,5,3,1,8,6,4,2,0};
        int[] rotatedArray = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}; 
        boolean rotation;      

        rotation = isRotated(original, rotatedArray);
        if(rotation == true)
        {
            System.out.println("The original array has been rotated!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The original array has not been rotated");
        }

        System.out.println("\n Watch what happens when the original array is compared to an array"
                         + " with contents \n [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]");

        rotation = isRotated(original, rotatedArray);
        if(rotation == true)
        {
            System.out.println("The original array has been rotated!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The original array has not been rotated");
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> userArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);

        System.out.println("This program can also rotate arrays that contain "
                         + "single digit integers.\n Enter 9 single digit "
                         + "integers separated by spaces");

        //*****************************************************
        userArray.add(scan.nextInt());
        for(int i = 0; i<userArray.size(); i++)
        {
            //*****problem
            if(???????? )
                break;
            else         
                userArray.add(scan.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("The array you entered is: " + userArray.toString() +"\n");

        rotateArray(userArray);

        System.out.println("When your array is rotated, it looks like this: \n" + 
                           userArray.toString());

    }

public static ArrayList<Integer> rotateArray(ArrayList<Integer> userArray)
    {    
        int replace = 0;
        int inc = 1;
        int indexVariable = 0;

        //if number of elements equals an even number
        if(userArray.size() % 2 == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < (userArray.size()/2);i++)
            {
                replace = userArray.get(i);                             
                userArray.set(userArray.get(i),userArray.size() - inc );
                userArray.set(userArray.size() - inc, replace);
                inc++;
            }
        }

        //if number of elements equals an odd number
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <(userArray.size()/2) ; i++) 
            {
                replace = userArray.get(i);                             
                userArray.set(userArray.get(i),userArray.size() - inc );
                userArray.set(userArray.size() - inc, replace);
                inc++;
            }
        }

        return userArray;

    }
```

Comment: `rotation==true` can be replaced with just `if(rotation)` since its a boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about the scanner is that when its reading from the console, `#hasNext` will only ever return false if the scanner is closed, such as when you close it or the console is no longer usable for input. Otherwise, calling it will tell the scanner to wait for input and will let you know if it is valid input (e.g if you call `#hasNextInt`).

So the best way IMO to solve your issue is to read the scanner as a string, then split it and process it yourself as follows.

```
String input=scan.nextLine();
    String[] numbers=input.split(" ");
    for(String number:numbers)
    {
        if(number.isEmpty())
            continue;//check for trailing so input like 3   4   5 is read
        userArray.add(Integer.parseInt(number));//You would want to add a catch here for invalid input.
    }
```

Comment: Just a  thought ... To cover entries where double-spacing (or more) might of happened use `.split("\\s+")` instead of `.split(" ");`. To ensure a valid string representation of a integer numerical value was supplied (and not a alpha character(s)) then use: `if (!number.matches("\\d") { ... }` instead of `if(number.isEmpty()) { .... }`.

Answer (score 0):

If `input: 1 2 3 4 5` and `userArray.size` should match `original.length` then you can do like this:

```
int size = original.length;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            userArray.add(num);
```

Or you can hardcode variable `size`:

```
int size = 9;
```

or input it from console:

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: > The reason as to why I included the arraylist is because I want to make the program dynamically allocate memory so that the user can enter as many single digit inputs as well. <

The OP doesn't want to have a set array size, therefore limiting it at the beginning won't help them in this case